# My jQuery Won't Work on My Webpage [Repost]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

All of my HTML and CSS code works fine, and my script is properly linked (or so I assume), but I can't get the script to load or do any actions I've coded. Here's my HTML, CSS, and JS code:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Highlights</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='testwebcss.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='testwebjs.js'></script>

    </head>
            <body>
        <div id="title" class="highlighted">I'm highlighted!</div>
        <div id="text">Highlight me, too!</div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

CSS

```
    #title {
    background-color: #C02942;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    }

    #text {
    background-color: #0B486B;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Vivaldi, Cursive;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .highlighted {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#text').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });

    $('#text').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
    });
```

So I don't understand why it's not working. As you can see, the script simply doubles the opacity when the mouse enters the perimeter of #text. So, why is nothing working. I got this from the console:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

## ***From the answers I received earlier, I setup a local webserver to run it on. I ran the webpage through it, but once again it would not run the jQuery.***

Fixed it; it has been working all along. Somewhere in editing my original code, I deleted a $, removing the selector from a working status.

Derp

Comment: you are not including jQuery in your page

Answer (score 0):

you are not including jQuery library in your page

To include the library using CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='testwebjs.js'></script>
```

Comment: I added that, but my webpage is still lacking jQuery capabilities.

Comment: I'm actually getting this in my JavaScript console:

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #text has no method 'click' testwebjs.js:2
(anonymous function) testwebjs.js:2
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
x.extend.ready jquery.js:433
q`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually load jquery.js into your page. That's why the $() function is undefined. Just add the following to your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please refer to the comments I have posted to Arun's answer above! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have used JQuery `($)` in your JavaScript code but JQuery library is not included into the page.

To include JQuery library from CDN add below `<script>` element into `<head>` section :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please refer to a comment I have posted on Arun's answer! Thanks!